# My reputation is way too low to comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, linked-accounts, privileges

I vigorously request that the reputation system be revised to let people with higher reputation in other Stack Exchange sites be able to comment on questions/answers.

A possibly reasonable approach would be to make your privilege based on an average: if the average is above the reputation needed to post comments, then users should be allowed to comment everywhere. To make the system maybe a tiny bit more "resistant" to problems, there could be a minimum reputation to hold in at least two accounts, and to have at least 3 accounts associated.

I don't know if this makes sense to you, but it would be greatly helpful because, well, it's not very nice to be deleted questions.

I am very willing to behave "well" but if I don't have enough points to comment, how am I supposed to?

Comment: If you have at least 200 reputation in any one account, you can get an association bonus that gives a one-time +100 reputation bonus to all accounts. This is sufficient enough to allow you to comment on every site. I'm not sure what the rest of your request is, especially given your title, but the point of "People with high rep on other sites should be able to comment" is already done.

Comment: The title and the content seem to conflict. You need 50 points to comment. Your title seems to say "I should need 100 or 1000 or more points to comment" but your body says "My points from other sites should count for commenting". Can you edit the title to match the content?

Comment: LOL sorry I am tired - title fixed.

Comment: You could've just edited 25 posts. Does seem annoying, but I've received 150+ rep just wasting away my day editing posts to get basic privileges. Then rep after that comes much easier.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When a user first reaches 200 reputation on a site, it will trigger 100 rep to be added to their associated account(s) (100 rep will also go to any accounts associated thereafter).

I see your highest account on Stack Exchange is on Stack Overflow where you have 171 rep. Gaining 29 more rep on Stack Overflow will enable you to start posting comments on every other associated site.

**Note**: 100 rep is the most that any account will ever benefit from this feature, i.e., later gaining 200 rep on another site will not trigger an additional 100 rep pay-out.

Comment: So, if I have a question but, asking it would make it a duplicate, and I can't comment what, do I do?

Comment: @GBikeZ8 Does the existing question solve your problem? If not, ask your question and include an explanation of what's different about your situation.

Comment: 's I appreciate your reply. Ok.