# Allow 1 rep users to comment if approved by 2 members?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, comments

Sometimes there are answers that should be comments, sometimes it happens because the user can't post a comment on questions/answers that he doesn't own. [Here is one example of that...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045983/basic-question-regarding-facebook-sessions-using-php/6433147#6433147)

> This isn't an answer, but the all-knowing stack exchange creators won't allow me to make a comment yet.... Stupid. ANYWAYS - is there a way to access this data through the Facebook PHP SDK? I see that it is setting a session variable and the signed_request is inside the session but I have not been able to find a method within the existing SDK that will actually allow me to access it when going to a different page within my application.. Do I need to extend the FB class and do this myself? ...

Should low rep users be allowed to post comments, **with approval**? Like when we approve or reject an edit from low rep users, **maybe we could approve or reject comments**.

There could be a higher character count required to post the comment and it could filter short posts with "thanks" and this kind of comments to reduce noise.

---

[Another example...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455592/access-c-array-within-blocks-variable-array-count-objective-c/6441705#6441705)

> no you don't have to release anything, it's just a reference to something that is not dynamically allocated
>
> thank you cefstat it worked for me :)

This was meant to be reply to @iPortable question about the answer on @cefstat answer.

Comment: Well-discussed request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/remove-reputation-minimum-to-comment http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53647/50-reputation-for-making-comments-is-too-high http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94388/my-reputation-is-way-too-low-to-comment

Comment: @Josh, those have no salt. - And by salt I mean: only with 2 approval votes they will be able to comment anywhere.

Comment: I think you're missing the point: these are Q&A sites - WE WANT USERS TO CONTRIBUTE Q&A. Not comments. Comments are incidental - grease for the wheels. If a user isn't contributing good Q&A, implementing some complicated system to try and drag good comments out of them isn't a good use of anyone's time.

Comment: And that "answer" is a *great* example of the sort of comment we don't really need...

Comment: @Shog9 ok, I just though of that because of the tons of `not an answer` flags I see...

Comment: @BrunoLM: yeah... Some users just can't take a hint. But giving them a free pass to post comments and then queuing them up 'til users with plenty of edits to approve, posts to edit, questions to close, and answers to write find time to reject them isn't going to improve matters.

Comment: @Shog9 The example I gave is awful, but it made me think of this idea. If the comment is required to understand the question it will probably be made by a member anyway. I will just keep flagging as `not an answer` then. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Take a look at this guinea pig: http://stackoverflow.com/users/779183/friar-tuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd personally prefer to see this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), for two main reasons:

1. Comments are, as noted by [@Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95980/allow-1-rep-users-to-comment-if-approved-by-2-members/#comment-241208) 'incidental' to the Q&A format, and intent, of the site. They allow for some discussion around the questions, or answers, but are not a focus.
2. The workload for the approval process would be in addition to the review process for new users' questions/answers, edits by low-rep users, flag-reviews, close vote-reviews...I **really** don't believe the end-result merits the work-load for the community.

Comment: The answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment/258670#258670 suggests how this comments with minimal reputation  can be allowed